# TFS Adding a new branch that is a total rewrite

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I am new to TFS and trying to figure out how to get my new rewrite of an existing application into TFS properly with Branching...

I have a project where I have three branches Dev Main and Prod

I just created a new branch off the Dev called Dev-branch-Rewrite I was able to get my code into the Dev-branch-rewrite but it doesnt show the main as being a branch I can merge to.  I have done something incorrectly.  Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

TFS forces a strict branch hierarchy, so you need to plan ahead. Currently I suspect that `main` is the parent of both `dev` and `prod` so in effect to go from `dev` to `prod` you have to merge via main.

The best practice would be to take the new branch for your rewrite from `main` this way you have a clear path to `prod` once the rewrite is done, but you can still support your users in the existing `dev` branch.

I.e

```
       Prod
         |
       Main
       |   |
       Dev  Dev2.0
```

As a side note, I'd try to keep your branch names as short as possible as you may start to hit the windows 260 character path limit.

For more information on branching strategies, read the [ALM rangers guidance on codeplex](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).